# \W matcher vs whitespace? Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to remove every non alphanumeric character from a word, however I rather keep whitespaces. Is it able to somehow join these two cases together?

```js
const word = 'dwa$-I| awd#4'.replace(/\W/g, '');
console.log(word); // whitespace removed =((
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[^\w\s]` which means you're excluding *alpha-numeric* and *space* character from the search.

```js
const word = 'dwa$-I| awd#4'.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, '');
console.log(word);
```